# Using require once or include to upload multiple scripts in a form

Tags: php, html

So i have this php script that handles uploading to multiple sites. There are about three sites in all, now they using the same class for uploading but with different API array..

Below is one of the scripts that handles the uploading...

```
class APIUpload
{
   private $data;

   public function __construct( Array $data )
   {
       $this -> data = $data;
   }

   public function doUpload()
   {
       $ch = curl_init();

       if ( is_resource( $ch ) )
       {
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload_api/' );

            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this -> data );

            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 );

            $data = curl_exec( $ch );

            curl_close( $ch );
       }

       if ( empty( $data ) )
       {
            $this -> error = 'An unexpected error occured.';

            return;
       }

       return $this -> parse( $data );
   }

   private function parse( $data )
   {
       if ( ! ( $json = json_decode( $data, true ) ) Or ( json_last_error() ) )
       {                                            
            $this -> error = 'There was a issue decoding the response.';

            return;
       }

       if ( isset( $json -> error ) )
       {
            $this -> error = $json -> error;

            return;
       }

       return $json;
   }

   public function getError()
   {
       return $this -> error;
   }
}

$message = null;
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' )
{
     /* Initialize Upload */
     $Api = new APIUpload([
      'name'     => $_POST[ 'name' ],
      'category' => $_POST[ 'category' ],
      'hash'   => $_POST[ 'apikey' ],
      'file'  => '@' . $_POST[ 'file' ],
      'description'    => $_POST[ 'descr' ]
     ]); 

     if ( ! ( $data = $Api -> doUpload() ) ) 
     {
          $message = $Api -> getError();
     }  
     else
     {
          $message = sprintf( 'Your file has been uploaded to: %s', $data[ 'ok' ] );
      }
      }

?>
```

Below the above php script, I have this html script that posts the values entered into the PHP fields....

```
<div style="color: #ff0000;"><?php echo $message; ?></div>

<form method="post" action="">

<fieldset>

<legend>API Example</legend>

<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">

<label for="file">File</label>
<select name="file" id="file">
<option value="">Select File</option>
<?php foreach ( glob( 'files/*.torrent' ) As $file ): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $file; ?>"><?php echo basename( $file ); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select name="category" id="category">
  <option value="0">Select A Category</option>
  <option value="50">Adult XXX</option>
  <option value="28">Anime</option>
  <option value="18">Apps</option>
  <option value="51">Books</option>
  <option value="10">Games</option>
  <option value="52">Mobile</option>
  <option value="1">Movies</option>
  <option value="22">Music</option>
  <option value="33">Other</option>
  <option value="70">Pictures</option>
  <option value="113">TV</option>
  <option value="71">Videos</option>
 </select>

 <label for="apikey">Apikey</label>
 <input type="text" name="apikey" id="apikey" value= "">

 <label for="description">Description</label>
 <input type="text" name="descr" id="description" value="Default description...">

 <input type="submit" value="Upload">

 </fieldset>

 </form>
```

So my problem is I have about three of these php scripts to do uploading to other sites, but how can I run this script so it can run the others at once...

So eg.. I have the following

site1.php
site2.php
site3.php

Main script has html form to run all at once...

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use multi curl for that which runs multiple request at once use something like this.

```
$urls = array($site1, $site2, $site3);
$url_count = count($urls);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $url_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$urls[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt( $curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload_api/' );
    curl_setopt( $curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this -> data );
    curl_setopt( $curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 );
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);
```

Comment: Lets say site 1 uses  `$Api = new APIUpload([
      'name'     => $_POST[ 'name' ],
      'category' => $_POST[ 'category' ],
      'hash'   => $_POST[ 'apikey' ],
      'file'  => '@' . $_POST[ 'file' ],
      'description'    => $_POST[ 'descr' ]
     ]);` and site two uses  `$Api = new APIUpload([
      'name'     => $_POST[ 'name' ],
      'categoryname' => $_POST[ 'category' ],
      'hashkey'   => $_POST[ 'apikey' ],
      'filename'  => '@' . $_POST[ 'file' ],
      'desc'    => $_POST[ 'descr' ]
     ]);`

Comment: In this example i used same values but you can add different values within for loop for each site, When initializing upload $Api = new APIUpload send an array with all sites array values like this array($site1_data_array,$site2_data_array);